# Laravel Eloquent - get count of another table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have an eloquent model "Athlete" and there is another table performances. Each athlete has 0 to many performances. And I would like get best performance of each athlete(personal best) or null if the athlete doesnt have any performances yet.

My athlete model:

```
class Athlete extends Model
{

    // I would like to do something like
    public $personalBest = max(performances) - the highest perfomance

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'athletes';

    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Get the performances for the Athelete post.
     *
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function performances()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EloquentModels\Performance', 'athlete_id', "id");
    }
}
```

I would like to get the highest performance of each athlete. Hope it does make sense.

I think it has to be answered somewhere but I had no luck finding it. So sorry if I just failed to find it.

```
Performances table
id(int) year(int) performance(float)
-------------------------------------
1       2000      257.3 
2       2001      227.3
```

Just to wrap things up. Posting the final raw query which was generated:

```
select [athletes].[first_name], [athletes].[last_name], MAX(performance) AS personal_best
from [athletes] 
left join [performances] on [athletes].[id] = [performances].[athlete_id] 
group by [athletes].[id], [athletes].[first_name], [athletes].[last_name] 
order by [personal_best] desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) should do the job

```
$athletes= App\Athlete::withCount('performances')->get();

foreach ($athletes as $athlete) {
    echo $athlete->performances_count;
}
```

If you want max performance, you can do something like

```
 $athletes= App\Athlete::all();

    foreach ($athletes as $athlete) {
        echo $athlete->performances->pluck('performance')->max();
    }
```

Something like

```
select e.athelete.id, max(perf.performace) as max_performace
from atheletes ath
  left join performaces perf on ath.id = perf.athelete_id
group by ath.id, max_performace
```

may be something like

```
DB('athletes as ath')::leftJoin('performaces as perf', 'ath.id', 'perf.athelete_id')->select(e.athelete.id, max(perf.performace) as max_performace)->orderBy('max_performace');
```

You can use `order by max_performace`, if you need.

I think you can also use simply

```
echo $athlete->performances->max('performance');
```

Comment: I dont need to count the performances I need to select the one highest performance(or null of athlete has 0 perfomance). Sorry if the description didnt give enough info.

Comment: @MarekBarta can you show demo data?, I have edited my question, but would like to see demo data to make it exact.

Comment: The perfomance is a float.. I have edited my question to show perfomances table

Comment: @MarekBarta Can you try my edited answer, using pluck to get `performance` collection and retrieve `max()`. I just tried to get costliest food item  in one of my project and I am getting correct value.

Comment: I think the edited answer does the trick... But just perfomance qestion isnt it possible to dont load all the perfomances when I only need to best one.. It could be hundreads of perfomances for each athlete

Comment: @MarekBarta give me just 2 minutes, I will generate the exact query from this and update the answer, that may help you, but in that case, I will suggest using a JOIN, and making using aggregate functions.

Comment: @MarekBarta, I think it will not give you great idea still the query I can log is `>>> App\models\FoodItem::pluck('price')->max()
"select `price` from `food_items` where `food_items`.`deleted_at` is null"
[]
0.68
=> 90.0
` let me write another answer and lets see, if that will give you better idea.

Comment: also one last thing I need the athletes be sorted by that personal best

Comment: @MarekBarta,I have edited my answer, that should give you a close idea, you should not expect us to do your job, that will not help you learning.

Comment: Absolutelly not trying to get the final code just to help how to get it. But I dont understand what you meant with the edited answer. I dont wanna(and cant) use raw sql query that why I'm torturing myself with eloquent. So how can I get that "max performance" and order athletes based on it?

Comment: @MarekBarta You can convert this to Query builder or eloquent query.

Comment: @MarekBarta my last edit may make your job easy just `$athlete->performances->max('performance');`

Comment: I acutally solve it with query builder instead of eloquent. So I will mark this as correct answer because your help helped me a lot. But just out of curiosity when I was trying to solve it with Eloqunt I couldnt find out how to order athletes based on they "max performance". How would you approach it?

Comment: @MarekBarta First can you try the last edits, that should also work fine, second, on your question if you can post your exact query, than I may see the issue.

Comment: I updated my question with the query and I will try the edits

Comment: @MarekBarta lets move to chat. and you can use `DB::listen(function ($query) { dump($query->sql); dump($query->bindings); dump($query->time); });` in tinker to generate your SQL query from your eloquent query, so that we will get the idea, where you are going wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199680/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-marek-barta).